# Loop Cut Not Going All The Way (No Ngons No Duplicates)

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges

I have a very simple mesh with all quad faces and no duplicate vertices. Still the XY loop cut doesn't go all the way round the mesh. Attaching the blend file for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 inner faces, you need to delete them, you can't loopcut through edges that are common to more than 2 faces:

[image]